# OpenGL ES code working in Android but not glAttachShader not working on iOS

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, opengl-es

I have some OpenGL ES C code that runs fine on Android. The code is poor quality (random error codes, using globals and such) because I'm just trying to get up and running before refactoring and cleaning. However, it works on Android and correctly displays a red triangle.

But the same code does not work on iOS. I get `GL_INVALID_VALUE` when calling `glAttachShader` (I commented the relevant line below), even though every prior call has succeeded.

Here is the code:

```
#include "gl_render.h"
#include "gl_wrapper.h"
#include <math.h>

GLuint globalProgramObject;
int surfaceWidth;
int surfaceHeight;

GLuint LoadShader ( GLenum type, const char *shaderSrc )
{
   GLuint shader;
   GLint compiled;
   GLenum error;

   shader = glCreateShader ( type );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -50;
   }

   glShaderSource ( shader, 1, &shaderSrc, NULL );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -51;
   }

   glCompileShader ( shader );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -52;
   }

   glGetShaderiv ( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -53;
   }

   if ( !compiled )
   {
      GLint infoLen = 0;

      glGetShaderiv ( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen );

      error = glGetError();
      if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
         return -54;
      }

      if ( infoLen > 1 )
      {
         char *infoLog = malloc ( sizeof ( char ) * infoLen );

         glGetShaderInfoLog ( shader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog );

         error = glGetError();
         if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            return -55;
         }

         free ( infoLog );
      }

      glDeleteShader ( shader );

      error = glGetError();
      if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
         return -56;
      }

      return -2;
   }

   return shader;

}

int on_surface_created(int width, int height) {
   surfaceWidth = width;
   surfaceHeight = height;

   char vShaderStr[] =
      "#version 300 es                          \n"
      "layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;  \n"
      "void main()                              \n"
      "{                                        \n"
      "   gl_Position = vPosition;              \n"
      "}                                        \n";

   char fShaderStr[] =
      "#version 300 es                              \n"
      "precision mediump float;                     \n"
      "out vec4 fragColor;                          \n"
      "void main()                                  \n"
      "{                                            \n"
      "   fragColor = vec4 ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );  \n"
      "}                                            \n";

   GLuint vertexShader;
   GLuint fragmentShader;
   GLuint programObject;
   GLint linked;
   GLenum error;

   vertexShader = LoadShader ( GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vShaderStr );

   if (vertexShader <= 0) {
      return -155;
   }

   fragmentShader = LoadShader ( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fShaderStr );

   if (fragmentShader <= 0) {
      return -156;
   }

   programObject = glCreateProgram ( );

   if (programObject == 0) {
      return -157;
   }

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -57;
   }

   // this is failing with GL_INVALID_VALUE
   glAttachShader ( programObject, vertexShader );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -58;
   }

   glAttachShader ( programObject, fragmentShader );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -59;
   }

   glLinkProgram ( programObject );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -60;
   }

   glGetProgramiv ( programObject, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -61;
   }

   if ( !linked )
   {
      GLint infoLen = 0;

      glGetProgramiv ( programObject, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen );

      error = glGetError();
      if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
         return -62;
      }

      if ( infoLen > 1 )
      {
         char *infoLog = malloc ( sizeof ( char ) * infoLen );

         glGetProgramInfoLog ( programObject, infoLen, NULL, infoLog );

         error = glGetError();
         if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            return -63;
         }

         free ( infoLog );
      }

      glDeleteProgram ( programObject );

      error = glGetError();
      if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
         return -64;
      }

      return -2;
   }

   glClearColor ( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -65;
   }

   globalProgramObject = programObject;

   return 0;
}

int on_draw_frame() {
   GLenum error;

   GLfloat vVertices[] = {  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
                         };

   glViewport ( 0, 0, surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -66;
   }

   glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -67;
   }

   glUseProgram ( globalProgramObject );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -68;
   }

   glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -69;
   }

   glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -70;
   }

   glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -71;
   }

   glDisableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );

   error = glGetError();
   if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
      return -72;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

For extra context, here is the Objective C code that I'm using to host the OpenGL worker:

```
#import "OpenGLRender.h"
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>

@interface OpenGLRender()
@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<OpenGLRenderWorker> worker;
@property (copy, nonatomic) void(^onNewFrame)(void);

@property (nonatomic) GLuint frameBuffer;
@property (nonatomic) GLuint depthBuffer;
@property (nonatomic) CVPixelBufferRef target;
@property (nonatomic) CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef textureCache;
@property (nonatomic) CVOpenGLESTextureRef texture;
@property (nonatomic) CGSize renderSize;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL running;
@end

@implementation OpenGLRender

- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)renderSize
                      worker:(id<OpenGLRenderWorker>)worker
                  onNewFrame:(void(^)(void))onNewFrame {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.renderSize = renderSize;
        self.running = YES;
        self.onNewFrame = onNewFrame;
        self.worker = worker;

        NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(run) object:nil];
        thread.name = @"OpenGLRender";
        [thread start];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)run {
    [self initGL];
    int result = [_worker onCreateWithWidth: self.renderSize.width andHeight: self.renderSize.height];

    if (result != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to call onCreateWithWidth %f AndHeight %f: %d", self.renderSize.width, self.renderSize.height, result);
    }

    while (_running) {
        CFTimeInterval loopStart = CACurrentMediaTime();
        result = [_worker onDraw];

        if (result != 0) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to call onDraw: %d", result);
        } else {
            glFlush();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), self.onNewFrame);
        }

        CFTimeInterval waitDelta = 0.016 - (CACurrentMediaTime() - loopStart);
        if (waitDelta > 0) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:waitDelta];
        }
    }
    [self deinitGL];
}

#pragma mark - Public

- (void)dispose {
    _running = NO;
}

#pragma mark - FlutterTexture

- (CVPixelBufferRef _Nullable)copyPixelBuffer {
    CVBufferRetain(_target);
    return _target;
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)initGL {
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
    [self createCVBufferWithSize:_renderSize withRenderTarget:&_target withTextureOut:&_texture];

    glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_texture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_texture));

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0, GL_RGBA,
                 _renderSize.width, _renderSize.height,
                 0, GL_RGBA,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, _renderSize.width, _renderSize.height);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_texture), 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthBuffer);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully initialized GL");
    }
}

- (void)createCVBufferWithSize:(CGSize)size
              withRenderTarget:(CVPixelBufferRef *)target
                withTextureOut:(CVOpenGLESTextureRef *)texture {

    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, _context, NULL, &_textureCache);

    if (err) return;

    CFDictionaryRef empty;
    CFMutableDictionaryRef attrs;
    empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                               NULL,
                               NULL,
                               0,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    attrs = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 1,
                                      &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                      &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFDictionarySetValue(attrs, kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey, empty);
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width, size.height,
                        kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, attrs, target);

    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                 _textureCache,
                                                 *target,
                                                 NULL, // texture attributes
                                                 GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                 GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                                 size.width,
                                                 size.height,
                                                 GL_BGRA, // native iOS format
                                                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                 0,
                                                 texture);

    CFRelease(empty);
    CFRelease(attrs);
}

- (void)deinitGL {
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &_depthBuffer);
    CFRelease(_target);
    CFRelease(_textureCache);
    CFRelease(_texture);
}

@end
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working on iOS despite working fine on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a GLES2 context (`kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2`) but you're using GLES3 shaders (`#version 300 es`).

I'm slightly surprised the error isn't caught by `glCompileShader` but I guess the iOS driver is deferring the actual compilation until `glAttachShader` is called.

Comment: Thanks vm. I actually found the same thing yesterday (honest!) but forgot to update this. And I found it by digging through things and realizing that the error handling logic in `LoadShader` was wrong. It _was_ actually detecting the compile issues but my code failed to surface the error correctly.